# How to combine two CompletableFuture<String> and return the accepted Strings in the form CompletionStage<List<String>>

Tags: java, completable-future

I am working on an existing code base and need the function return type to be `CompletionStage<List<String>>`.

Here is a sample code to understand.

```
   private static CompletionStage<List<String>> getTwoMsgs() {
        CompletableFuture<String> msg1 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(()->getMsg()); //getMsg involves an Http request
        CompletableFuture<String> msg2 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(()->getMsg());
    
        return {placeholder};
    }
```

Please help.

Comment: You could return `msg1.thenCombine(msg2, List::of)`, see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#thenCombine-java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage-java.util.function.BiFunction-.

Comment: @sp00m Cannot resolve method 'of'.

Comment: @MohammedShirhaan *"Cannot resolve method 'of'"* - probably because you're using JDK 8? Then try `thenCombine(msg2, Arrays::asList)`.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko that worked. Thank you so much. Also when we store the result of this function in - CompletionStage<List<String>> msgs = getTwoMsgs();

What is the best way to loop over it and print the list items?

Comment: To perform some kind of side-effects (like print the elements) you can use `thenAccept()` which expects a Consumer: `msgs.thenAccept(list -> list.forEach(System.out::println));`

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko The main thread exits before the thenAccept() finishes. Any better way to handle it? I see some StackOverflow answer which says to use ForkJoinPool.commonPool().awaitQuiescence(1000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

Comment: @MohammedShirhaan Threads in the  CommonPool are so-called **daemon threads**, for that reason, when the `main()` done with its job it doesn't wait for those folks to finish. You can provide an Executor as a second argument of `supplyAsync()`.

Comment: You can just chain `join()` at the end. `msg1.thenCombine(msg2, Arrays::asList) .thenAccept(list -> list.forEach(System.out::println)) .join();`